# ComboBox is not accepting Null for a selected Item

Tags: sql, sql-server, wpf, datagrid

I'm getting the following exception:

> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format

I am getting this exception message because I have a `Selection Change Event` populates `Comboboxes` and `TextBoxes` with data from the selected row from the `DataGrid`

My `ComboBox` shows the selected item from the `DataGrid` row and when the drop-down is clicked it shows the remaining `Selected Item List`

If the row selected from the `DataGrid` is `NULL` then I am getting this exception message because my `ComboBox` does not recognize `Null` as one of the Items from its list.

Here is my code for the `Selection Change Event` and my I am getting this exception on line `cmb_DisputeClassification.SelectedValue = row_selected["FR_DSP_CLSF"].ToString();`

```
        private void dtGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        // When a respective row is selected
        // Populate the key dispute information in botton left panel. 
        DataGrid gd = (DataGrid)sender;
        DataRowView row_selected = gd.SelectedItem as DataRowView;

        if (row_selected != null)
        {
            // Customer Information Menu
            txt_acct.Text = row_selected["ACCOUNT"].ToString();
            txt_custname.Text = row_selected["CUST_NAME"].ToString();
            txt_address.Text = row_selected["PREM_ADDR"].ToString();
            txt_revclass.Text = row_selected["RateType"].ToString();
            txt_DisplayID.Text = row_selected["DSP_ID"].ToString();



            // Dispute Information Menu - Review Section

            // Review Notes Textbox
            txt_ReviewNotes.Text = row_selected["FR_CMMNT"].ToString();
            txt_ResolutionNotes.Text = row_selected["COMMENT"].ToString();
            DatePicker_ScheduledFor.Text = row_selected["FR_SO_DT_WNTD"].ToString();
            txt_WFMissuedBy.Text = row_selected["NM_USER"].ToString();


            // First Review Parse is needed for ShortDate format.
            if (row_selected["FR_DT_FIRSTREV"] != null)
            {
                DateTime dateTime;
                if (DateTime.TryParse(row_selected["FR_DT_FIRSTREV"].ToString(), out dateTime))
                {
                    txt_firstreview.Text = dateTime.ToShortDateString();
                }
                else
                {
                    txt_firstreview.Text = ""; //assign default value
                }
            }

            // First Review Parse is needed for ShortDate format.
            if (row_selected["FR_TS_LATESTUPD"] != null)
            {
                DateTime dateTime;
                if (DateTime.TryParse(row_selected["FR_TS_LATESTUPD"].ToString(), out dateTime))
                {
                    txt_Latestupdate.Text = dateTime.ToShortDateString();
                }
                else
                {
                    txt_Latestupdate.Text = ""; //assign default value
                }
            }

            // Comboboxes 

            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=WINDOWS-B1AT5HC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CustomerRelations;Integrated Security=True;");

            try
            {
                // Dispute Classification ComboBox
                SqlDataAdapter Status_data0 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [hb_DspClsf]", connection);
                DataSet ds0 = new DataSet();
                Status_data0.Fill(ds0, "t");

                cmb_DisputeClassification.ItemsSource = ds0.Tables["t"].DefaultView;
                cmb_DisputeClassification.DisplayMemberPath = "TXT_DSP_CLSF";
                cmb_DisputeClassification.SelectedValuePath = "KY_DSP_CLSF";
                cmb_DisputeClassification.SelectedValue = row_selected["FR_DSP_CLSF"].ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: So what exatly does `row_selected["FR_DSP_CLSF"]` return at runtime? Did you debug your code to find out?

Comment: @mm8 Yes I did and the `SelectedValue` it's returning is `Null` and the `SelectedValuePath` it's returning is `""`

Comment: I didn't ask what `SelectedValue` returns, did I? What is "FR_DSP_CLSF"? Do you think this is clear from reading your question? It's not...

Comment: It's returning a value that ranges from 1-14. And then it displays the `Selected Value Path` from my `hb_DspClsf` table in the database. and that table is named `TXT_DSP_CLSF`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is not caused by the Combobox but by the `ToString()` call on the same line, which you cannot call on a `NULL` reference.

```
string myString = null
myString; //no error
myString.ToString(); //error
```

However this problem can be avoided using `Convert.ToString()`.

```
string myString = null
Convert.ToString(myString) //no error
```

Comment: This worked, thank you!